# Delete row script deletes contents but not the row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this function and it archives perfectly but doesn't delete the full row afterwards. Its just removing all the information and conditional formatting I have. I haven't got a clue what I am doing wrong :(

```
function onEdit2(passedEvent) {  
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = passedEvent.source.getActiveSheet();
    var r = passedEvent.source.getActiveRange();

    if(s.getName() == "Orders" && r.getColumn() == 9 && r.getValue() == "5.     Archive") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 1, 2, numColumns).moveTo(target);
        s.deleteRow(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is deleting the actual row for me.

Comment: Why do you use: `var s = passedEvent.source.getActiveSheet();` instead of `var s = ss.getActiveSheet();`?  The active sheet is the active sheet.  It's not dependent on the `passedEvent`

Answer (score 0):

there are times when the scripts seem to trip over themselves. You might try flushing the spreadsheet prior to deleting the row.

```
 s.getRange(row, 1, 2, numColumns).moveTo(target);
 SpreadsheetApp.flush();
 s.deleteRow(row);
```